# Are stack snippets down?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

When I try to run an example I get:

> #### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> #### Runtime Error
>
> **Description**: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> **Details**: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a `<customErrors>` tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This `<customErrors>` tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>   </system.web> 
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> **Notes**: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's `<customErrors>` configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.
>
> ```
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>   <system.web>
>     <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>   </system.web> 
> </configuration>
> ```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I broke it trying to change our build configuration. Sorry about this. Good news: I am now a manager so I will break things less often (but maybe people more often?).

Comment: In my experience, if you become a manager you may break things less often, but you do it much more spectacularly!

Comment: @Ben we will see if this is true.

Comment: @Ben you've never had a manager say "well, I guess I'll go open up ${ide} myself... I used to be a programer too you know..."?  (hint to avoid this: change the VCS system as soon as a programmer is promoted to a manager to make it harder for them to check in broken code)

Comment: Of course @michael, occasionally done it myself, hence the experience. Luckily I have a fantastic team and we're all still learning together, so I'm not completely lost yet.